# How to efficiently compute the Game of Life on the GPU using WebGL/OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, webgl, gpu

For computing automatas on Open/WebGL, my naive approach would be to encode the state of the automata as a texture, treating each pixel as an automata cell; then I'd call a fragment shader that texture, computing the next state and rendering it back. I'd then repeat the process indefinitely.

My issue is: wouldn't that cause the memory to be transferred between CPU/GPU at each invocation of the fragment shader? Ideally, I want to call the fragment shader several (thousands) of times without any communication between CPU/GPU; possibly, making good use of processing units local memories.

Is that possible?

Comment: https://github.com/skeeto/webgl-game-of-life, https://github.com/xpl/life, http://patater.com/life/, http://www.tamats.com/blog/?p=409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you need to transfer a texture data through CPU when calculating next state?

You will need two textures. Put your cells' current state into one of them and use a shader to draw next state into the second texture. Then do the opposite: Draw next state into the first texture while using second one as a current state. Repeat this as many times as needed.

Comment: Ah, okay. Is that the best that can be done with WebGL, though? I believe with CUDA you could use a single texture and keep cells more time in a single computing unit, doing several passes without sending anything to the global memory; correct?

Comment: @Viclib *Is that the best that can be done with WebGL, though?* I haven't used WebGL, but if it works more or less same as OpenGL, then the answer is probably "yes". I can't imagine a better solution for this problem. | *I believe with CUDA...* And I haven't used CUDA, so I can say nothing about it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!